# Using a variable file name in C to read from multiple files with similar names?

Tags: c, file, syntax

I have multiple files named sensor0.txt, sensor1.txt, sensor2.txt and so on. I need to open these files, do calculations with them, and print them on the screen.

So I thought of something like,

```
for(i = 0; i < N/*(Number of files)*/; i++)
{
 fpointer = fopen(/*not sure how to format this*/)
 //calculations I need to perform with said file
 //Print results of calculations on the screen
 }
```

I can't quite find a straight forward solution to this. Is this even possible? Or must I create some arrays and store all the information, and then do calculations with all of said stored information.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use an array of characters to store the names of the files.
2. Create the name of the files using the value of `i`.
3. Open the file in the for loop and read the contents.

```
char filename[50]; // Make it large enough
for(i = 0; i < N/*(Number of files)*/; i++)
{
   // Construct the filename.
   sprintf(filename, "sensor%d.txt", i+1);

   // Open the file.
   fpointer = fopen(filename, "r");
   if (fpointer != 0)
   {
      //calculations I need to perform with said file
      //Print results of calculations on the screen
      fclose(fpointer);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of this sprintf function your explanation was very clear and appreciated! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use **sprintf** function to create your file name. Ex: `sprintf(filename, "%s%d.txt", "sensor", number)`. After that, open file with this name normally

Comment: Why use `%s` here? Writing arbitrary input into a `printf` or `sprintf` can be deemed "unsafe", but surely that is not a problem with the immutable  string "sensor"?