# Opening all the files from a local directory/folder

Tags: c, file-io

Using Visual Studio 2015 how would i open and read all the file in a directory.

The Input Parameters for the program are

1. **Number of Sensors (N):** Determines the number of input files
2. **File Location:** A local directory/folder where the files are located. Each file will be named: `sensor_0.txt`, `sensor_1.txt`, ... `sensor_(n - 1).txt`

I can open and read individual files in the directory by hard coding them using `fopen`, but since the number of input files is not constant I don't know how I would read all of the files in the directory regardless of how many input files there are.

I was thinking that i would need to create the file names since the only thing changing in the file names is the sensor number but that doesn't seem to work since `fopen` requires a `const char *` file name.

I have searched for solutions and i found a `DIR` variable type in `dirent.h` header file, but that doesn't work with the the Visual Studio Compiler and a package needs to be installed in order to use that header file.

I am in an intro to programming class so i feel like installing outside programs would be the wrong approach to solving this issue, but I could be wrong. I have also looked into functions like `FindFirstFile`, and `FindNextFile` but those also seem too advanced for me.

Any help would be really would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is a bad idea, there is a limit for open file descriptors if there are enough files to go beyond that limit your program will fail. Also, have you tried *gcc*, there are many IDE's for windows with that compiler. And finally consider another OS too. But that depends on other things.

Comment: @iharob -- I don't think manny needs to open all of the files at the same time, just open them all sequentially (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @keithmo Maybe, but just in case...

Comment: ".. that doesn't seem to work since fopen requires a const char * file name" – that cannot be the problem. The `const` only says that `fopen` is not allowed to change the file name, but *you* can! Please add your not-working code to your post.

Comment: @Jongware Nice observation, why would that be a limitation would be good to know by looking at the actual code.

Comment: Apart from the fact that one of your colleagues asked the question, this is substantively the same question as in [Using a variable file name in C to read from multiple files with similar names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978711/) (the file names are a giveaway).

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a Windows-specific application (rather than something that needs to be portable to other operating systems) then look into the [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx), [FindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx), and [FindClose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364413(v=vs.85).aspx) APIs.

Here's a sample of how to use these APIs (based somewhat on the samples from the above links):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s [target_file]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Target file is %s\n", argv[1]);

    hFind = FindFirstFile(argv[1], &FindFileData);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("FindFirstFile failed, error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    do {
        printf("File name = %s\n", FileFindData.cFileName);
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));

    FindClose(hFind);
    return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't had a Windows dev environment years, so I have no way to compile & verify this sample. It should get you pointed in the right direction, though.

Comment: Here I think link-only isn't *that* bad if the OP didn't already state that he looked at these functions and also included that he was using Windows -- if your answer showed him something he didn't already know about. But since he did, pointing him to documentation he probably already looked at isn't very useful unless you go into a bit more detail and show some very simple examples or something.

Comment: Much better. This is a real answer. I am very happy to read your code, lately i've been seeing a lot of inconstent style and bad use of white space, your code is beautiful, it feels good to read it, and it's really easy to understand.

Comment: While a good answer in itself, it overlooks that the filename should be `sensor_NUM.txt`. The first step is to limit the files found to `sensor_*.txt`, and then additional code is needed to ensure the `*` matches only digits. Since OP asserts that the files are named ".._0", ".._1" and so on, it's way easier to construct the correct filename right away. Also, OP does not mention it as a potential problem, but perhaps it's required that the files should be read in numerical order.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it by hardcoding the base name and iterating with an index to generate the specific name, something like this

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; ; ++i)
{
    char filepath[MAX_PATH];
    FILE *file;
    // In principle, you should check the return value to ensure
    // it didn't truncate the name
    snprintf(filepath, sizeof(filepath), "sensor_%d.txt", i);
    // Try to open the file, if it fails it's probably because
    // the file did not exist, but it's not the only possible
    // reason.
    file = fopen(filepath, "r"); // Or "rb", depends ...
    if ((done = (file == NULL)) != 0)
        break; // Cannot open this, probably there are no more files.
    // Process the file here
}
```

A better way would be to pass the name to another function, so you can later change the name generation method by looking at the directory instead of assuming it.

**NOTE 1**: Secure c Runtime, in MSVC compiler will probably complain about `fopen()` and `snprintf()` since `snprintf()` uses the POSIX name style or something like that (perhaps using the safe version `snprintf_s()`) I don't remember. But this is standard c (as per C11) so it should compile with any c compiler.

**NOTE 2**: You should also, use the full path unless the files are in the CWD. Something like (assuming the files are in drive `"C:"`)

```
snprintf(filepath, sizeof(filepath), "C:\\full\\path\\sensor_%d.txt", i);
```